# Find a 5-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Z_5$ and determine its basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Find a 5-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb Z_5$ and determine its basis.

**Attempt:**
I pick $V = P_4(\Bbb R)$, the set of all polynomials of degree less or equal than $4$ with the coefficients are in $\Bbb R$.
The basis is $B:=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$. Here's why $B$ be the basis.

Spanning: Since each polynomials $p \in P_4$ can be written as
$p = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4$, which is a linear combination of $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$, then
$\text{span}(B) = V$.

Linearly independent: Denote $p_0=1,p_1=x,p_2=x^2,p_3=x^3, p_4 = x^4$. To show that the only coefficient satisfying the vector equation $a_0p_0+a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3+a_4p_4 = 0 ... (0)$ are $a_i = 0$ for all $i\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. But, the equation (0) is equivalent to the statement that
$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4 = 0 ... (1)$ for all $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$. So, we must show that this is true iff each coefficient in $(1)$ is zero. But, each coefficient in $(1)$ must be zero. Otherwise, the left side of the equation would be a nonzero polynomial with infinitely many roots. On the other hand, a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots. Thus, the equation $(0)$ has only trivial solution.

Therefore, $B$ is a basis of $V$. In particular, $\dim(V) = 5$.

Am the above true ? What if I pick $V = P_4(\Bbb Z_5)$ ? Firstly, I pick it and know that the standard basis (as above) not form a basis, since $0=5=10$, etc, and hence it's not linearly independent.

Comment: The problem with the example you chose is that it's not clear what the vector space structure is. How are you proposing to use an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ to scale elements of $P_{4}(\mathbb{R})$? If you are proposing to just consider the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ as the integers $0,...,4$ (which are not the same thing!), then are you sure that's a linear operation? For example, if you sum 5 copies of the same non-zero polynomial then you are multiplying by 5, which means the result is 0, which is not 5 times the polynomial - this does not satisfy the definition of "vector space".

Comment: What do you mean by "Find" a vector space? We can just declare a vector space. For example let $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ be a basis and put $V = \{a\alpha_{1}+b\alpha_{2}+c\alpha_{3}+d\alpha_{4}+e\alpha_{5} \mid \alpha_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{5} \}$.

Comment: I pick a wrong V, and now I pick z5^5 as V, so closed for me

Answer (score 1):

Any such will be isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{5^5}$.  You could take the quotient $\Bbb F_5[x]/p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible fifth degree polynomial. Again a basis would be $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$.

Comment: This is confusing. We certainly **could** do this, but there is no need to consider quotienting out the ring of polynomials just to get a vector space, and certainly no reason to do so by an irreducible polynomial. I am also confused why we would consider a vector space as being isomorphic to a field; this field certainly **can** be considered as an $\mathbb{F}_{5}$-vector space, but I would never say that an arbitrary vector space was isomorphic to a field.

Comment: For example, $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]/(x^5-1)$ is also a 5-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{5}$, and is certainly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{5^{5}}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers As a vector space over $\Bbb Z_5$, yes, it is isomorphic. As an algebra over $\Bbb Z_5$, it is not isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks @MorganRodgers  I was thinking vector space isomorphic, but am always at risk of overstepping my bounds.

Comment: @MorganRodgers But we don't care about the algebra structure. Vector space is all that matters here. So it turns out that they are all isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{25}$.

Comment: @Arthur It can be ambiguous to say they are isomorphic without qualification, especially if both structures **do** have a multiplicative operation, and while $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ can naturally be considered a vector space over any subfield, this notation **emphasizes** that it has more algebraic structure than a simple vector space; so my point is, it is strange to say such a vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{5^5}$ (and to emphasize a quotient ring construction) if we do not need to introduce a multiplication operation for any reason.